# A linear algebra problem about linear subspace of $GL_n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, problem-solving

> Assume $A_1,\dots,A_n$ are fixed $n\times n$ real matrices and satisfy that for any nonzero vector $v ∈ \mathbb R^n$, the vectors $A_1v,\dots,A_nv$ form a basis for $\mathbb R^n$. Find the integers $n$ such that the matrices $A_1,\dots,A_n$ exist.
> List examples of matrices $A_1,\dots, A_n$ for those $n$.

I found this problem in a book about linear algebra. I've solved the problem for $n=1,2,4$ and odd numbers before I posted the problem. At first I thought this problem is just about the matrices, but when observing the examples for $n=1,2,4$ I noticed that the problem has something to do with the product structure of $\mathbb R^n$ and this insight allows me to solve this problem.

Comment: Such example does not exist if $n>1$ is odd.

Comment: Yes.Thanks for you answer but I've already known this.What I want to know is if such example exists when n>2 is even

Comment: @祝浩然 Note that askers are expected to provide context for their questions, as is [explained here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Please [edit] your question to tell us where you found this problem, what you have tried so far, and any other thoughts that you have on the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reminding.

Comment: You already seem to have the answer, but for posterity here is a nice initial step. The given condition is equivalent to the statement that for all $c_1,\dots,c_n$ not all zero and all $v \neq 0$, it holds that $(c_1A_1 + \cdots + c_nA_n)v \neq 0$. Equivalently, for all $c_1,\dots,c_n$ not all zero, it holds that $(c_1 A_1 + \cdots + c_n A_n)$ is an invertible matrix.

Comment: This allows us, for instance, to see that the situation cannot occur for odd $n > 1$. Indeed, for odd $n > 1$, the polynomial $p(t) = \det(A_1 t + A_2)$ must have a root $t \in \Bbb R$, so that $t\,A_1 + 1\cdot A_2 + 0\cdot A_3$ cannot be invertible for all $t \in \Bbb R$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is $n=1,2,4,8$.
The existence of $A_1,\dots,A_n$ is equivalent to the existence of a division composition algebra on $\mathbb R^n$.
This is because we can assume $A_1=I$ by substituting $v$ by $A_1^{-1}v$. Then fix a vector $v\neq 0$. Let $(v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n)$ denote  $(A_1v,\dots,A_nv)$ which is a basis of $\mathbb R^n$. Then we define $v_iw=A_iw$ for any $i$ and $w$, and using distribution law we can define $(a_1v_1+\dots+a_nv_n)w$ for all $(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ in $\mathbb R^n$. One can easily verify that this gives a division composition algebra of $\mathbb R^n$. By applying Hurwitz Theorem one knows that $1,2,4,8$ are the only answers.

Comment: Can you give a more detailed explanation? I'm also interested in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I post this answer since I cannot post comments. I am not so sure about the $n=8$ case since the octonion algebra is not associative.
Furthermore, a composition algebra comes equipped with a nondegenerate quadratic form hence I am not sure we can apply the classification theorem for division algebras and exploit it for an existence result.
I think also that the assumption $A_1=I$ deserves clarification, for example in the case $n=2$ we can choose $A_1=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\ 0&-1\end{pmatrix}$, $A_2=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\ 1&0\end{pmatrix}$, even if it's true that we can multiply each $A_i$ by an invertible matrix $U$ and obtain a set with the same independence property, $I\notin\operatorname{span}\{A_1,A_2\}$.

Comment: Indeed,the oction algebra is not associative,but there's no need for it to be associative.The nondegenerate quadratic form can be obtained by defining $N(v)=a^2_1+⋯+a^2_n $for $v=a_1v_1+⋯+a_nv_n$ and $(u,v)=(N(u+v)−N(u)−N(v))/2$

Comment: I see. I misunderstood the answer. My fault. Furthermore, in order to be self-contained one has to show that $\mathbb{C}$, $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{O}$ can be instantiated as a matrix algebra (easy).