# Maximal number of linear independency in $GL_n\cup\{0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, galois-theory

Let $GL_n(\mathbb{F})$ be the set of all invertible $n$-by-$n$ matrices over a field $\mathbb{F}$. For the set $GL_n(\mathbb{F})\cup\{0\}$, it is trivial that it contains $0$ and $1$ dimensional subspaces as its subset.

What's the maximal dimension of subspaces that is subset of $GL_n(\mathbb{F})\cup\{0\}$?

**My Progress**

When $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{R}$:

- It is $1$ when $n$ is odd.
- It cannot exceed $n$ for all $n$.
- It is exactly $n$ if and only if $n=1,2,4,8$. (This is from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4418390/a-linear-algebra-problem-about-linear-subspace-of-gl-n?noredirect=1&lq=1).)

Comment: Surely the set of all $\begin{pmatrix} x & y\\ -y&x\end{pmatrix}$ is a 2-d space when $n=2$?

Comment: I believe this is answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1696618/vector-subspace-of-m-n-mathbbr-with-invertible-matrices). I cannot vote to close as a duplicate, as there is an open bounty.

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut Thank you for mentioning.

Answer (score 2):

For $n$ odd $GL_n\cup\{0\}$ does not contain any two-dimensional subspace. Indeed, for any $A,B\in GL_n$, which are linearly independent, i.e. $A$ is not a multiple of $B,$ there exists $\lambda$ such that $A-\lambda B$ is not invertible. Indeed
$$A-\lambda B=(AB^{-1}-\lambda I)B$$ The matrix $AB^{-1}$ has a real eigenvalue $\lambda$, as the dimension is odd. Then $AB^{-1}-\lambda I$ is not invertible.

For even $n$ the set $GL_n\cup\{0\}$ contains a two-dimensional subspace.
Denote $n=2m.$ Let $A\in GL_{2m},$ have all eignevalues unreal.  Then the two-dimensional space
generated by $A$ and $I$ is contained in $GL_n.$ For example $A$ could be the direct sum of $m$ matrices of dimension  $2\times 2$
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
-1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Will $GL_n\cup\{0\}$, if $n$ is even, contain even higher dimensional subspaces? Actually I'm hoping that it can contain a subspace of dimension $n$.

Comment: I do not know yet.

Comment: Many thanks anyway!

Comment: I have impression that your question is closely related to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4418390/a-linear-algebra-problem-about-linear-subspace-of-gl-n/4419151#4419151

Comment: I believe his question is equivalent to my first question. Actually, thanks to your help, I have got a proof that for any even $n$, $GL_n\cup\{0\}$ has a $2^{n-1}$ dimensional subspace as a subset. But in your question, 祝 said it's true if $n=1,2,4,8$, which I cannot understand. And actually, my second question remains unanswered.

Comment: Alright, it seems that my proof is wrong...

Comment: It seems that an advanced old result called the Hurwitz theorem is involved. Perhaps you can find connections to that.  See https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://student.fau.edu/sclanton/web/presentation.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiCqorfgvj2AhUqpIsKHWdaCsoQFnoECBIQAQ&usg=AOvVaw2EXlYu4PfqkR_1ZyFgM-e2

Comment: Is this about the Universal Algebra?

Comment: That's not my specialty. I have just googled the term" composition algebra" mentioned in the answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4418390/a-linear-algebra-problem-about-linear-subspace-of-gl-n/4419151#4419151

Comment: Alright. This is also strange to me, and it requires effort to understand this. Thanks a lot for this great discussion!