# A vector space of invertible matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This problem is from Yufei Zhao's handout on Linear Algebra:

Let $n$ be an integer and $f(n)$ be the maximum dimension of a subspace of matrices in $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ such that the only uninvertible matrix in the subspace is the zero matrix.

1. Show that $f(n)\le n$.
2. Show that if $n$ is odd then $f(n)=1$
3. Find all $n$ such that $f(n)=n$

4. Find a closed form for $f(n)$.

My approach: 1 is easy, one can just take $n+1$ (row 1)s and make row 1 zero.

2 Suppose there are two matrices call $A,B$. Clearly $det(A), det(B)\ne 0$. Consider the polynomial $det(xB-A)$. It has leading coefficient $det(B)x^n$ so it is a polynomial of odd degree and thus has an odd root.

I found that $f(2)=2$ but I am stuck on questions 3 and 4. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Regarding part 3, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4418390/81360) and its comments.

Comment: Alright, I will learn Hurwitz algebra.

Comment: here is his page for handouts: https://yufeizhao.com/olympiad/   Which one mentions your Hurwitz problem?

Comment: Actually, the handout I am referring to is here: https://yufeizhao.com/a34/ps/linear-algebra.pdf The post linked by Ben mentions the Hurwitz theorem that I don't know too much about

Comment: @KaiWang  Thank you.  If you want a person to become aware of a comment,  you should begin it with an @  sign  and the first few letters of their user name.  That way, a little sign appears on their screen  in the upper right (as long as they are still looking at this site).  I don't know any easy books on this, see T. Y. Lam(2005), Introduction to Quadratic Forms over Fields.  For a longer discussion, he recommends D. B. Shapiro (2000),  Compositions of Quadratic Forms.   Anyway, books on quadratic forms